How to maximise the absolute Rayleigh quotient of a non-Hermitian matrix?
The Rayleigh quotient of a Hermitian matrix $M$:
$$R= \dfrac{\boldsymbol{a}^\dagger M \boldsymbol{a}}{\boldsymbol{a}^\dagger \boldsymbol{a}}$$
is maximized for $\boldsymbol{a}$ the eigenvector of $M$ with maximal eigenvalue.
As an extension to this, my question is: how to maximise $|R|$ when $M$ is non-Hermitian?

When $M$ isn't Hermitian, the quantity $a^\dagger M a$ isn't even guaranteed to be real, so it doesn't make sense to ask about maximizing it. Are your matrices/vectors $a$ at least in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

To deal with the realness issue, you could take the norm of both the numerator and denominator.  It changes the question a bit, however.

You're right sorry, what I meant is the absolute value of $R$, I just modified.

Some thoughts.
Let
$$M_1 := \frac{M + M^\dagger}{2}, \quad M_2 := \frac{M - M^\dagger}{2\mathrm{i}}.$$
Then, $M_1, M_2$ are both Hermitian,
and $|a^\dagger M a|^2 = (a^\dagger M_1 a)^2 + (a^\dagger M_2 a)^2$. The problem becomes:
$$\max_{a^\dagger a = 1}\, (a^\dagger M_1 a)^2 + (a^\dagger M_2 a)^2. \tag{1}$$
This is multivarite quartic polynomial optimization with quadratic constraint.
Here is an approximation for (1): (1) is equivalent to
$$\max_{\mathrm{tr}(X^2) = 1, \, \mathrm{rank}(X) = 1, \, X \succeq 0}\, \mathrm{tr}(M_1 X M_1 X) + \mathrm{tr}(M_2 X M_2 X). \tag{2}$$
Here, $X$ is Hermitian.
We have
$$\mathrm{tr}(M_1 X M_1 X)
= \mathrm{vec}(X)^\dagger (M_1^\top \otimes M_1)\mathrm{vec}(X), \quad \mathrm{tr}(X^2) = \mathrm{vec}(X)^\dagger \mathrm{vec}(X).$$
(2) is equivalent to
$$\max_{\mathrm{vec}(X)^\dagger \mathrm{vec}(X) = 1, \, \mathrm{rank}(X) = 1, \, X \succeq 0}\, \mathrm{vec}(X)^\dagger (M_1^\top \otimes M_1 + M_2^\top \otimes M_2)\mathrm{vec}(X). \tag{3}$$
If we drop the constraints $\mathrm{rank}(X) = 1$ and $X \succeq 0$, we solve the following relaxation of (3):
$$\max_{x^\dagger x = 1}\, x^\dagger (M_1^\top \otimes M_1 + M_2^\top \otimes M_2)x. \tag{4}$$
Here $x := \mathrm{vec}(X)$.
Let $x_0$ be the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue of $M_1^\top \otimes M_1 + M_2^\top \otimes M_2$.
Let $X_0 := \mathrm{ivec}(x_0)$.
Based on $X_0$, find a $a$ which is approximation to (1).

Very nice, thank you. I think point (1) is the most useful to me but the rest is quite clever too.

@user655870 Perhaps there are some known algorithm to deal with the form (1).
